# phonegap form submission wthout image or jquery

Tags: forms, cordova

This is what I have below, the only way I can submit my form is by browsing for an image.
Can somebody please tell me how to submit this with a button, preferably without jQuery.
I only want to submit a form with text, no images. Thanks!

```
function browse()
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
        function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        { 
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
    );
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI)
{
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = document.getElementById('file_name').value + "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how you can submit an image from the camera to your server without having to have a file input form element, where the user has to browse for the file etc.

The easiest answer is simply not to store the image as a file, but keep it as a base64 string. To do this, change your destination type to

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

The parameter to your success function will now be a base64 string, which you can send to your server much like any other string. You'll then need to base64_decode it server-side, and then write it to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try a normal HTML form:

```
<form action="/post" method="post">
  Input: <input type="text" value="input something"/>
  Submit: <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: imageURI... can I use an image from inside the app, a one pixel image as the URI??

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to submit a form to a URL for an image.